# Why solving Helmholtz equation using FEM gives solution when theory says no?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-element-method, elliptic-equations

I get problem when solving $-\Delta u(x,y) - k^2 u(x, y) = f(x, y)$ in $(0, 1) \times (0, 1)$, $u = 0$ on the boundary.

When $k^2$ equals an eigenvalue, says $k^2 = 2 \pi^2$, using the Fredholm alternative, theorically we can say the problem is not well-posed, that we cannot obtain a unique solution for the problem. I solve this problem with $k^2 = 2 \pi^2$ using Finite Element Method, with $f(x, y) = 10 e^{-100(x^2 + y^2)}$, and there's no error. The matrix is of full rank. So I don't understand why we still have a solution, which is maybe unique (the matrix is of full rank). Where did I make mistake?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numerical eigenvalues are not the same as the exact eigenvalues (but close). When you refine the mesh the numerical eigenvalues approach the exact ones and the problem becomes *ill-conditioned* (but still of full rank).